# Opencv:Can't get predict confidence on faceRecognizer

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

When I run the predict(src) function of a faceRecognizer, it returns only a int, instead of a int and a double.

using help() throws this:

Help on built-in function predict:

```
predict(...) method of cv2.face_BasicFaceRecognizer instance
    predict(src) -> retval  or  predict(src) -> label, confidence  or  predict(src, collector[, state]) -> None
```

The code I'm using is:

```
nbr_predicted, conf = recognizer.predict(imgp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug: http://answers.opencv.org/question/82294/cant-get-predict-confidence/

Recieved answer in original question.